# Disabling a Framework Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm looking to disable certain parts, or at least modify, the `MailMessage` class found in `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` through the .NET Framework. The reason for this is that I'm overloading it in my email class to provide some extra functionality. This class is then inserted into a MongoDB database and then retrieved in a `List<Email>` format. The code looks like this:

```
  public List<Email> GetAllEmails()
    {
        //! A try statement performing the logic of the function
        /*! We're creating a MongoDB collection of type EmailMessage named collection and then returning that collection
         */
        try
        {
            MongoCollection<Email> collection = GetEmailsCollection();
            return collection.FindAll().ToList<Email>();
        }
```

The class I'm using for the inheritance, the `Email` class, is as follows:

```
public class Email : MailMessage
{
    private DateTime date;

    public Email (MailAddress from, MailAddress to)
    {
        this.From = from;
        this.To.Add(to);
    }
    public Email(string from, string to)
    {
        MailAddress addressFrom = new MailAddress(from);
        this.From = addressFrom;

        this.To.Add(to);
    }
    public Email(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailAddress addressFrom = new MailAddress(from);
        this.From = addressFrom;

        this.To.Add(to);

        this.Subject = subject;

        this.Body = body;
    }
    public Email()
    {

    }

    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

When I run the program I encounter an exception in the line:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileFormatException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while deserializing the HeadersEncoding property of class System.Net.Mail.MailMessage: Instance is read-only.

Is there any way for me to change the properties of HeadersEncoding inside System.Net.Mail.MailMessage or any other way to store and retrieve the class Email?

Comment: What `Email` class are you referring to?

Comment: Hello Patrick. The MailMessage class that's part of the .NET Framework. I shall edit my question to make this more clear as well.

Comment: But what is `List<Email>` then? How does it convert from / to `MailMessage`?

Comment: Just use another class of your own.

Comment: `MailMessage` doesn't serialize/deserialize.  Instead of trying to break the .NET Framework, just store your data in your own custom objects and use the built-in mail sending objects just for *sending* mail.

Comment: Hi David! I was thinking about doing that, but for memory and code readability reasons I was hesitant to do so, as I'm creating an API for another programmer and wanted it as efficient as possible. I'm guessing that this is the only way. Just write that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct and close the question.

Comment: @mentor07825: I assure you that code readability and supportability will be a lot better if you separate different concerns into their own objects rather than try to hack the inner workings of the .NET Framework :)

Comment: @David: You're right. I'll do that. I'll get to work on it and then modify my tech document to reflect the changes. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use AutoMapper to easily copy properties from MailMessage to your class and back. http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: don't try to use `MailMessage`. It doesn't support serialization so you won't be able to save an instance of it in a file or in a database.

Write your own implementation of your `Mail` object with the specific properties you actually want to save/load from your DB, then provide a method that takes it as parameter and internally calls the standard function from `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` to send your mail.

Comment: ken2k got in there first before David. Marking it as correct and upvoting. Thank you everyone.